# RStudio data.frame Viewer turns data.frames to lists on user-defined `View` methods

Tags: r, rstudio

Does anyone have an idea (or a 'solution') that in case you define a `View()` method for a S4 class in which you would like to access a certain slot in the RStudio data.frame Viewer it just won't return it as expected?
What I mean is if you start a fresh R session eg

```
View(mtcars)
```

will work as expected and deliver
[image: RStudio-DataFrame-Viewer]
(works as expected including Filters etc in the Viewer)

But then if you define some S4 class eg

```
foo <- setClass("foo", slots = c(df = "data.frame"))
myfoo <- new('foo', df = mtcars)
```

and then a `View` method

```
setMethod("View", "foo", function(x, title) View(x@df, title))
```

You will suddenly face one of these (two differing) messages:

```
Creating a generic function for 'View' from package 'stats' in the global environment
```

OR this one

```
Creating a generic function for 'View' from package 'utils' in the global environment
```

Which imo is already "disturbing" since afaik the `stats` package does not seem to even have a `View` function.

But lets continue and get to what I really wonder about. Which is why I do not get the expected same result in RStudio's data.frame Viewer but some form of list view?

[image]

Can this somehow be avoided and made to produce the expected ie same type of "View" as for the standalone `data.frame`?
And to top it all off once you do that within a R package you end up with this (final pic below) where in the background you see `View(mtcars)` output before `devtools::load_all()` was run and in the foreground you see the result of `View(mtcars)` after `load_all()` picked up all methods/functions in the package? Is that a RStudio bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (not-so-nice) workaround until a better solution comes along.

```
foo <- setClass("foo", slots = c(df = "data.frame"))
myfoo <- new('foo', df = mtcars) 

old <- View
View <- function(...) {
    if(isS4(...)) {
        unclass(...)@df |> format.data.frame() |> old()
    } else {
        old(...)
    }
}
```

The viewer with the red lines is the default `utils::View`,

```
function (x, title) 
{
    check <- Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_", "")
    msg <- "View() should not be used in examples etc"
    if (identical(check, "stop")) 
        stop(msg, domain = NA)
    else if (identical(check, "warn")) 
        warning(msg, immediate. = TRUE, noBreaks. = TRUE, domain = NA)
    if (missing(title)) 
        title <- paste("Data:", deparse(substitute(x))[1])
    x0 <- as.data.frame(x)
    x <- as.list(format.data.frame(x0))
    rn <- row.names(x0)
    if (any(rn != seq_along(rn))) 
        x <- c(list(row.names = rn), x)
    if (!is.list(x) || !length(x) || !all(sapply(x, is.atomic)) || 
        !max(lengths(x))) 
        stop("invalid 'x' argument")
    if (grepl("darwin", R.version$os)) 
        check_for_XQuartz()
    invisible(.External2(C_dataviewer, x, title))
}
```

RStudio modifies `View` *somewhere*<sup>1</sup>, maybe [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/a8e6b693e26880d50cbfb04d6a3d3198637f4d9e/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionDataViewer.R#L767-L770) to a more user friendly interface, via

```
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
```

where `original` is `utils::View`, ( see `e <- environment(View); e$original`).

---

<sup>1</sup> I have not figured out (yet) where exactly.

Comment: yeah I also found that `.rs.callAs()` func but did not find out that specific environment; btw I also found the `.rs.viewDataFrame()` function , which almost does the right thing but then it  also looses the `Filter` functionality and as soon as some generics get registered also starts behaving 'weird' later on. But I will give yr above approach a shot - and of course if it solves my

Comment: @GWD The more I look at this the more I think this is not supposed to be done and error prone. `.rs.__` functions should be considered [private](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1579#issuecomment-335899016). That said, [here](https://github.com/D-Se/newview) is a toy repo that passes CMD check that does the thing, but is obviously not production-ready

Comment: tbh I did not think about that (neat) `unclass` and `old` way you came up with but was stuck with calling those ``.rs.` functions, which I also agree should not be the preferred method - gonna get back at you tomorrow on that topic